# What programming language is IIS written in?

Tags: c++, iis, programming-languages

I'd like to know this information for IIS versions 6.0, 7.0 and 7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is made in C++, microsoft has given isapi extension which is api for IIS and programmers can explore classes using this api

Comment: Not so funny. Your response was "probably" and "might".
Ganesh's response was "It is" and a brief proof.

Answer (score 10):

Probably [`C++`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/), the core that is, newer versions such as 7 might have extensions written in other languages from the [`.NET`](http://www.microsoft.com/NET/) family.